# Why the value of the "datetime-local" is null when I change the date?

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

Look at this image to understand better the problem:

[image]

The code to send the form is this in jquery using `$form.serialize()`

```
$.post(  $form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function (response) { 
 ...
});
```

And finally the html code is this:

```
<form action="ServletNewActivity" method="post" id="formNewActivity" novalidate>
...
<label>Hora y fecha de inicio</label>
<input type="datetime-local" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" value="<%= dateFormat.format(date) %>T08:00" required/>
<small class="error">La hora y fecha de inicio especificadas no son válidas.</small>

<label>Hora y fecha de finalización</label>
<input  type="datetime-local" name="fecha_fin"  id="fecha_fin" value="<%= dateFormat.format(date) %>T10:00" required/>
<small class="error">La hora y fecha de finalización especificadas no son válidas.</small>
<small class="error actividad_genera_conflicto">
    La actividad que usted desea ingresar genera conflicto con otra actividad existente en el mismo rango de tiempo, por favor elija otro rango de tiempo para crear la actividad.
</small>
...

<input type="submit" value="Crear actividad" name="crear" id="crear"/>

</form>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my country, there is no April 31.  You should remove `novalidate` attribute of `form` element.

Also, see http://crbug.com/231811

Comment: What's the matter with your country? I need to set any datetime I want... .....???

Comment: What country do you live?